# RAM not detected duble boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: windows-10, memory, ubuntu-18.04

I have an Asus X456U with dual boot, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

One day I removed the RAM installed in order to check it. Since then, whenever I turn off my notebook for more than 30 minutes and then turn it on, the RAM is not detected on either OS.

If before turning it on, I remove the RAM and then place it back again either of the OS detects it.

Anyone have an idea of what could be the trouble?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the RAM stick, check if any dust particle inside the slot, blow some air, clean it, push the RAM stick properly.

Comment: I already did that and the problem stills

Comment: You did some damage and have done your best, but the problem remains. It might be best to ask a professional repairman.